# How to set or implement automationId property to NavigationPage class or Navigation back button in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to set AutomationId in the navigation back button in order to automate the testing. I am using Xamarin forms default navigation back button, so where I need to add the AUtomationId.

Please help me to solve this issue.